# Golang convert pdf to image by bimg

Tags: pdf, go

The example code below convert pdf to jpeg by using [bimg](https://github.com/h2non/bimg#convert).

```
func main() {

    buffer, err := bimg.Read("test.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }

    newImage, err := bimg.NewImage(buffer).Convert(bimg.JPEG)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }

    if bimg.NewImage(newImage).Type() == "jpeg" {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "The image was converted into jpeg")
    }

    bimg.Write("test.jpg", newImage)

}
```

But it only convert 1st page of `test.pdf`.

Is there any way that convert to image that contain more than one page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

bimg uses libvips, and can [potentially load PDFs](https://github.com/h2non/bimg/blob/master/vips.h#L365).
Unfortunately, the [default for libvips loading PDFs](http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-pdfload) is to load one page only.
Unless you want to modify bimg ([vendor](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories), [contribute](https://github.com/h2non/bimg), hack the source, etc.) you're out of luck.

Not an answer to the question (not using bimg), but you can use imagemagick instead,

```
import "gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick"
func main() {
    imagick.Initialize()
    defer imagick.Terminate()
    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()
    mw.ReadImage("test.pdf")
    mw.SetIteratorIndex(0)        // This being the page offset
    mw.SetImageFormat("jpg")
    mw.WriteImage("test.jpg")
}
```

Comment: Thank Patrick, I have run example above with some test files and imagick.v2. Somehow, some large files ( > 15 pages ) was fail, but with two, three pages pdf file is ok. I dont know why??, but anyway thank you, it's enough for me.