# Is there any way converting a PDF to jpeg with golang?

Tags: linux, pdf, go, jpeg

I am currently rewriting my "old" Python-based Chatbots into golang.
One issue I came across was that I can´t convert a PDF into jpeg. Which I´d like to do so I can send it into a chat easily.

Already tried this with bimg (did not work at all) and imagemagick (gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick) as provided in this answer to another thread: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/47520596/7502507"

```golang
imagick.Initialize()

defer imagick.Terminate()

mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()

defer mw.Destroy()

mw.ReadImage(pdf)

mw.SetIteratorIndex(0) // This being the page offset

mw.SetImageFormat("jpg")

mw.WriteImage(image)
```

It does not produce a jpg at all, it just gives me the error

```
ERROR_POLICY: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408
```

How can I make this work? I can´t seem to edit the security settings for this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps it could be something solved with elevated privileges?

Comment: Apparently it is due toa  bug in Ghostscript, you have to modify you `policy.xml` or update the Ghostscript package (a fix has been published) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Answer (score 7):

I've been through the same issue and din't find any pure Golang solution.

Not a pure Golang solution, but [this](https://github.com/brunsgaard/go-pdfium-render) works flawlessly which uses [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) internally. Underlying library is [Pdfium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/master/public/) which is a C++ library, developed by Google and used in Chrome.

After a lot of research, I discovered that Pdfium was the best in class in terms of speed, robustness, license requirements and reliability.

To improve overall performance of the operation, I've ended up with [this](https://github.com/antonini/golibjpegturbo) encoder as Golang's image encoders aren't geared towards performance and are [slow](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ATOWYGuZbfI).

Comment: potentially better lib available: https://github.com/klippa-app/go-pdfium